# How to bind Fallthrough Attributes to a slot?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Say, I have the following template:

```html
<ComponentA class="class-a" v-if="cond" />
<ComponentB class="class-a class-b" v-else />
```

I'd want to dry the code by using some `Fallthrough` component like this:

```html
<Fallthrough class="class-a">
  <ComponentA v-if="cond" />
  <ComponentB class="class-b" v-else />
</Fallthrough>
```

, whereas the `Fallthrough` component is defined like this:

```js
<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
};
</script>

<template>
  <slot v-bind="$attrs"></slot>
</template>
```

I expect this code to work, but unfortunately, it does not (the attributes aren't passed). I've double checked that `v-bind="$attrs"` works if switching `slot` to `div`, so the slot is definitely the problem. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Try to scope the `$attrs` in the slot like :

```html
<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
};
</script>

<template>
  <slot v-bind:attrs="$attrs"></slot>
</template>
```

then use them like :

```html
<Fallthrough class="class-a" v-slot="{attrs}">
  <ComponentA v-if="cond" v-bind="attrs" />
  <ComponentB class="class-b" v-else v-bind="attrs"  />
</Fallthrough>
```

Comment: Can confirm it's working. While this solution adds flexibility, there may be a way to further reduce the boilerplate code, to avoid explicit `v-bind` in the children.